# Android: Couldn't able to install own build without uninstalling previous build : INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE

Tags: android, gradle, build

We, as team, building an android app. We couldn't able to build and install our working version of app in a device, unless we uninstall the other team member's build in that device. If I'm alone working on it, the build is always successful. The error thrown by gradle is

`Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [INSTALL\_FAILED\_UPDATE\_INCOMPATIBLE but app not installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617703/install-failed-update-incompatible-but-app-not-installed)

Comment: have you tried to use the same keystore for all team members?

Comment: just uninstall the older build

Comment: @lal I didn't try that. Let you once I done.

Comment: Uninstalling the older build works, but isn't any other way without uninstalling ? because I'm losing user data. @WillTorres

Comment: some is different in the new build like permissions, api level, package name etc

Answer (score 2):

sincerekamal

Sometimes when you unisnstall a debuged app with the phone the package stills on the same preferences place (that's just an android bug). Yeah, you havent the app but the phone thinks you still having it.

Then, just uninstall this package from that place:

**1.- go to cmd
2.- execute "dir c:\your_folder_to_sdk\platform-tools"
3.- execute "adb uninstall your.app.package"**

note: If you have your path to adb alredy installed on your windows/mac system, the step 2 is not necesary

Comment: not working for me, cmd executes like forever.. and produces no-output